# Ranged accuracy

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

I have a player in my group that is playing a hybrid ranged rogue/executioner.The campaign has many options for the perma-hidden build he has.  He wants to make the character more accurate, he now has a +19 to hit with out combat advantage with a hand crossbow.I am at a loss as to how he could get better than a +22 with combat advantage. Could someone help?

```
====== Created Using Wizards of the Coast D&D Character Builder ======
Khaine D. Blackwood, level 12
Shade, Rogue/Assassin (Executioner), Cloaked Sniper
Guild Attacks (Hybrid) Option: League of Whispers (Hybrid)
Hybrid Assassin (Executioner) Option: Hybrid Executioner Fortitude
Hybrid Talent Option: Rogue Tactics (Hybrid)
Rogue Tactics (Hybrid) Option: Cunning Sneak (Hybrid)
Scion of Shadow (+2 to Stealth)
Theme: Scion of Shadow

FINAL ABILITY SCORES
STR 11, CON 15, DEX 22, INT 9, WIS 11, CHA 19

STARTING ABILITY SCORES
STR 10, CON 13, DEX 17, INT 8, WIS 10, CHA 15


AC: 27 Fort: 21 Ref: 26 Will: 22
HP: 82 Surges: 7 Surge Value: 20

TRAINED SKILLS
Acrobatics +17, Athletics +11, Intimidate +15, Perception +14, Stealth +30, Thievery +17

UNTRAINED SKILLS
Arcana +7, Bluff +12, Diplomacy +10, Dungeoneering +6, Endurance +8, Heal +6, History +5, Insight +6, Nature +6, Religion +5, Streetwise +10

POWERS
Basic Attack: Melee Basic Attack
Basic Attack: Ranged Basic Attack
Scion of Shadow Utility: Eyes of Night
Shade Utility: One with Shadow
Assassin Attack: Bola Takedown
Assassin Attack: Quick Shot
: Swap Daily For Poison Recipe
Assassin Attack: Assassin's Strike
: Swap Second Daily For Poison Recipe
Warlock's Curse  Power: Warlock's Curse
Rogue Attack 1: Unbalancing Shot
Rogue Attack 1: Sly Flourish
Shade Utility 2: Fleeting Shade
Stealth Utility 2: Elude Senses
Rogue Attack 5: Bloodbath
Rogue Attack 7: Snap Shot
Assassin Utility 10: Walk Through Shadow
Cloaked Sniper Attack 11: Sudden Bolt
Cloaked Sniper Utility 12: Unseen Shot

FEATS
Level 1: Hybrid Talent
Level 6: Cursed Shadow
Level 8: Hidden Sniper
Level 9: Crossbow Expertise
Level 10: Backstabber
Level 11: Grounding Shot
Level 12: Distant Shot
Level 12: Student of Malediction

ITEMS
Adventurer's Kit
Hand crossbow
Crossbow Bolts
Bracers of Archery (heroic tier) x1
Bola
Bloodroot Poison
Poisoner's Kit
Rapier
Protean Silk
Signal ammunition
Thieves' Tools
Bloodstinger Poison (level 3)
Potion of Healing
Carrion Crawler Brain Juice
Eyes of the Eagle (paragon tier) x1
Shadowdancer's Gloves x1
Cloak of Displacement +2 x1
Hidden Rapier +2 x1
Camouflaged Clothing
Footpads
Charlatan's Kit
Homing Hand crossbow +3 x1
Shadowflow Drowmesh +3 x1
Boots of Stealth (paragon tier) x1
Shadow Master Ki Focus +3 x1
====== End ======
```

Comment: What level is this? You'll need to give us his build as well for us to help you with any kind of accuracy.

Comment: Sorry i would shrink the comment into an Sblock sadly i lack the knowledge of how

Comment: is he missing? at all? cuz that's like 75% accuracy at L12.

Comment: his vision was to be more of a sniper, so hes fairly happy with the damage of the build, so hes now looking at his to hit

Comment: tbh it's already basically maxed (unless you want to give him a +4 magic weapon, or he swaps to a +3 prof weapon, but that means moving from cbs). To me that damage is not very much and there are good ways to get more of it. Unless there are good situations reasons for it I'd consider trading Grounding Shot and Distant shot for Moar damage, particularly I'd seriously consider suggesting Frost Cheese, he's got some feats that are...situational that would do well to be traded in for Lasting Frost and Wintertouched. Add a frost weapon and that's a +5 Damage boost and easy CA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a dagger. If range is an issue, use Weapon of Long Range, you can attack enemies 20 squares away without any penalty. This gives access to the following feats:

- Deft Blade, great accuracy boost if you use a lot of RBAs
- Nimble Blade, you should have CA every time because of Hidden

You have to pick another at-will power instead of Quick Shot, but your RBA after Deft Blade is much better anyway. Even without the feats, despite smaller [W], DPR goes up because of the higher accuracry.

> Generally speaking, if your average damage is higher than your chance of hitting times 20, increasing the accuracy by one gives more DPR than increasing the damage by one: if you hit 15 times out of 20, and your average damage is higher than 15, you should increase your attack.

Depending on how much you move in Hidden, you might consider changing the Hybrid Talent Option to Rogue Weapon Talent. It is +1 to attack with Daggers or Crossbows.